# Where can i use a try/catch block in my game?

Tags: exception, methods, try-catch

This is my game i created, i just need to add a try catch into it somehow and i am stuck.

```
/**
*
* @author 
*/
import java.util.*;
public class magiceightball {
public static void main (String [] args){
    questions();
} 
public static void questions(){ //method      

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball Game!");
        System.out.println("Shake(Type 'Shake' to have you question answered, or type 'No more'to end the game");
        String request = input.nextLine();
```

I think here is where i can add a try

```
        if (request.equalsIgnoreCase("shake")){
    answer();
    }
        else if(request.equalsIgnoreCase("No more")){
        break;
    }
        else{
        System.out.println("Invalid answer. Please try again!");
    }
}

}

    public static void answer(){

    switch(shake()){
        case 1:System.out.println("It is certain");
            break;
        case 2:System.out.println("It is decidedly so");
            break;
        case 3:System.out.println("Most likely");
            break;
        case 4:System.out.println("Ask again later");
            break;
        case 5:System.out.println(" Better not tell you now");
            break;
        case 6:System.out.println("Don't count on it");
            break;
        case 7:System.out.println("My reply is no");
            break;
        case 8:System.out.println("My sources say no");
            break;
        case 9:System.out.println("Unlikely");
            break;
        case 10:System.out.println("Doubtful");
            break;
    }

}
        public static int shake(){
```

This is another area i think could use a try and catch to check for arithmetic

```
    Random rand = new Random();//using random numbers
        int randomInt = rand.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;//i used this to get a random number from 1-10
        System.out.println(randomInt);
        return randomInt;
        }
}
```

Comment: your main code goes in try block where you implement your logics and if some how logics failed then it goes in catch blog where you handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Since exceptions are intended primarily for handling errors or other exceptional/unexpected events, a good candidate for such would be your `answer()` method. Imagine what could go wrong that you might not expect.

For example, what happens when your `shake()` method returns a value that cannot be handled by your `switch` statement? Consider a situation in which you increased the range of your random number generator and forgot to add additional cases; or, you didn't dynamically load enough answers from a configuration file.

A simple solution may be to add a `default:` case that returns some "catch-all" answer (e.g. "I don't know"). However, a better solution would be having the `default:` case throw an `Exception` to indicate that your method does not have answers for some rolls.

```
int roll = shake();
switch ( roll ) {
   ...
   default:
       throw new Exception( "No answer for roll: " + roll );
}
```